# Excel - Conditional row from an array to COUNTIF from VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, lookup, countif

I don't know if I'm going about this the wrong way but it seems like it should be simple. Column A has a list of Names. Along each row is several "W"'s. Another separate field has a drop down representing Column A names. I want to count the number of "W"'s in a row corresponding to what name I select. I've tried using VLOOKUP and COUNTIF but I can't figure out how to select the entire array and then single out the one row that matches my selected name. I can get it working with a bunch of IF statements but thats far too time consuming as I'm manually matching the name to the row (and it isn't future proof).

Comment: Can you show us some example data and the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to first 'narrow in' on the row you're looking for, after which point you can use a simple COUNTIFS to check the number of W's in that row.

One method would be to simply use INDIRECT, and create the row reference on the fly, like so [assumes your search cell is C1]:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(MATCH(C1,A:A,0)&":"&MATCH(C1,A:A,0)),"W")
```

This first uses MATCH to find the appropriate row, and then builds a reference to that row [like "24:24"], which becomes the row that INDIRECT passes to COUNTIFS, which counts that row for W's.

For only one use of INDIRECT, the high computing costs of INDIRECT should not be an issue.

Another method would be to point out the full possible box that data could be contained in [let's assume that at most only column H would be used], and then use INDEX to give us the appropriate row number, like so:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDEX(A:H,MATCH(C1,A:A,0)),0,"W")
```

This again uses MATCH to find the row which contains the value found in C1 within column A. Then it takes the full possible box from INDEX, and returns all columns from the particular row [note that telling index to return 0 for the column # actually returns all columns instead].

Other methods would be possible [for example OFFSET], but I believe these two show the principle fairly well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "Helper" Column method:

[image]

In the helper column:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:H2,"W")
```

Then use SUMIF() in the totals column:

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$9,K2,$I$2:$I$9)
```